# Smallest value of the expression $a^2+4a\sin b-4\cos^2b$

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

Need to find the smallest value of the expression:
$$a^2+4a\sin b-4\cos^2b$$
I would be glad to receive ideas/hints.

Comment: Transform the squared cosine...

Comment: By the way, this is not an equation.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
  a^2+4a\sin b-4\cos^2 b
  &= a^2+4a\sin b+4\sin^2 b-4 \\
  &= (a+2\sin b)^2-4 \\
  &\ge -4
\end{align}